# Can I run the RPI driver in ArchLnux?

Tags: archlinux, xorg, driver, framebuffer

The [RPI driver](http://elinux.org/RPi_Xorg_rpi_Driver) perports ([source](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=28294)) to bring accelerated Xorg performance by routing X output through a frame buffer driver.

The wiki page has clear [instructions](http://elinux.org/RPi_Xorg_rpi_Driver#Installation_of_the_driver), but they are very specific to Raspbian, including untaring files on top of the root file system replaces stuff from the package manager. I would rather not run Raspbian and instead use ArchLinux.

Is it possible to use this driver under Arch and if so, what procedure should I use to make it happen?

Comment: This is interesting. I'll give this a go when I'm back in front of my Pi!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to me that there's anything in the instructions that makes it specific to the Raspbian distribution (other than the opening sentence).

However, I assume that the tar files than contain Xorg-server will untar directly to the directory where X lives in Raspbian, overwriting it. This is probably not the same place as in Arch.
Bear this in mind if you give it a go.

If you don't fancy corrupting your SD card then I'll update this answer when I've tried myself next week :)

Comment: The paths seem to be mostly the same, but the whole thing was compiled against libraries not present or older than those in ArchLinux. It seems to have taken kindly to a few symlinks, but I was unable to get everything jury rigged. So. Close.